# Is it Possible to connect my local wamp server into a live website

Tags: wamp

I have uploaded my website on a web hosting with cpanel. how can i connect my website on local database? so i dont need to create database in my cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that a hosting company will allow you to connect a LIVE webserver on there hosted service to a database on your home PC.

You will have to backup the database and restore it to a database hosted within your hosting package. Look at the cpanel menus, and you should see a phpMyAdmin, use that to create a database on the hosting companies server and then restore your local backup to that.